# How can I "convert" a blender model into a 2d drawing?

Tags: modeling

[image]

As one can see, behind the "Koro" text, there is the outline of the lama.

How is this effect created? Are there any options in the compositor to do so?

How can I "convert" a blender model into a 2d logo?

Many thanks ;)

.blend file: https://mega.co.nz/#F!9QMGCTxL!PIc910mkaEhot_dlYFeQQg

Comment: Why not render it from the side? I'm afraid I don't really understand the question...

Comment: @gandalf3 Ok... How can I change the 3d object as a "2d shape", so that nothing sticks out, e.g. think of a drawing of a lama e.g.: http://imgs.steps.dragoart.com/how-to-draw-a-cartoon-llama-step-6_1_000000011669_5.jpg

Comment: For this case I think all you need is a shadeless material.

Comment: @gandalf3 If you won't mind, please post your response as an answer! Thanks ;)

Comment: If you want outlines like in the picture you linked, you could try using [freestyle](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Freestyle).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another option is to use the *Material Override* option in *Properties > Renderlayers* to override all the materials with a flat gray shadeless material.

For example:

1. Create a shadeless gray material:

   [image]
2. Use it as the renderlayer override:

   [image]

### Result:

[image]

Comment: Nice and clean solution, and fur looks awesome! How long did it take to render?

Comment: I chose this answer as it also included several screenshots, which is useful to locate the buttons, well-deserved!

Comment: @codemanx I don't remember exactly, but not long (I would estimate about a minute).

Comment: @gandalf3: thanks, just wondered, 'cause my Blender hung at "Preparing scene data" longer than your entire render time. Dunno what was wrong.

Comment: @CoDEmanX You could try disabling some things like AO and environment lighting in *World* settings, but other than that I guess it's just all that hair ;). BTW, I rendered again and the time is `1:06.61`.

Answer (score 6):

A very straight-forward solution:

- Create a new material and pick a *Diffuse* color
- Enable the Shading option *Shadeless*
- Replace all materials by this new material
  (did not work for Koros eyes for some reason, I replaced them with UV spheres and assigned the shadeless material)
- Disable the sky for rendering
  (I removed the entire node setup to get rid of it)
- Switch *Viewport Shading* to *Textured*
- Change to *GLSL* Material Mode in the N-panel *Shading* options
- Change to ortho sideview (in this case <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>)
- *Render OpenGL* and save image as PNG with alpha

Result (click for hi-res):

[image]

Note that it doesn't include simulated hair, but on the other side, render time was < 1 sec.

Comment: OMG all these answers are so good! I have no idea which to choose!

Answer (score 1):

Set the horizon color to white. Switch off all lights (including ambient occlusion). This will render a black outline, if you have a single object without background objects.

[image: silhouette]

Answer (score 1):

If you are going for a 2D logo at the start, I would recommend using curves. They're easier to manage (in certain ways) than a plane.

1. Add a Bezier Circle and change it's type to 2D in the shape settings:

   [image]
2. Model your logo:

   [image]

   *(Don't ask what this is supposed to be. I was going for a dinosaur thing, but it came out as more of a snake/cat thing)*
3. Set your camera to orthographic and position it in front of your logo.

   [image]

   [image]
4. Remove your lights from the scene and set the material to shadeless. Pick whatever colors you want.
5. Add text (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Add Text*) pick a font in the object settings, give it a shadeless material.
6. Voilà:
   [image]

Comment: I would +1 just because of "catlizard", but I don't think this really answers the OP's question of "How can I *'convert' [an existing] model* into a 2d logo?". Still, useful info.

Comment: I agree with gandalf3, but I still upvoted your answer